# Why doesn't DIR show C:\Users\Yours Truly\AppData?

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

[Pardon the Windows-noob question!]

It often happens that the paths I can read off the Windows Explorer GUI do not correspond to anything I can see with `DIR` (in the `CMD` command line).

For example, if I run this in `CMD`:

```
C:\>dir "Users\Yours Truly"
```

the output does not show anything resembling `AppData`, and yet

```
C:\>cd "Users\Yours Truly\AppData"
```

succeeds, and now the `CMD` prompt reads `C:\Users\Yours Truly\AppData>`, and, unsurprisingly, running `CD` without arguments just confirms this:

```
C:\Users\Yours Truly\AppData>cd
C:\Users\Yours Truly\AppData
```

---

I can think of two possible explanations (though I'm sure there are many more):

1. `C:\Users\Yours Truly\AppData` is not a "real" path; it gets translated to the real path behind the scenes;
2. `C:\Users\Yours Truly\AppData` is an "invisible" path, not normally displayed by `DIR`;

(Certainly, 1 and 2 are not mutually exclusive: `C:\Users\Yours Truly\AppData` could be a special type of *shortcut* that is not displayed by `DIR` (at least by default).)

Could someone shed some light on this situation?  If (1) is true, how can I find out the "real" path?  If (2) is true, how can I instruct `DIR` to display paths like `C:\Users\Yours Truly\AppData`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's marked as hidden.  You *can* view it if you do `dir /ah "C:\Users\Yours Truly"`... or `dir /ad "C:\Users\Yours Truly"`.  (ah = all hidden files, ad = all directories including hidden)

Another quick shortcut to get there is: use

```
CD %appdata%\..
```

`%appdata%` is an environment variable that defaults to your current appdata folder.  In Windows, this can be roaming, local, or localnew.  Almost everything uses `C:\Users\Yours Truly\AppData\Roaming`... so in most cases it's probably better just to use the `%appdata%` variable instead of the parent directory of `%appdata%`.

Comment: This is actually complicated. `dir /ah`, `dir /ad` `dir /ahd` and `dir` all show lots of different data, filtering in ways that are difficult to intuit. Each will show you some of the contents of your directory with some other data hidden. If you just want a list of _all_ the files and directories in some directory, as you would do with "ls -la" in Unix, let me suggest you get bash for windows or Cygwin and use the Unix tools, which are easier to understand, at least for me.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin I am a *nix guy myself, and I can truly appreciate the `ls` command, and its simplicity.  That being said, I believe suggesting bash for windows or cygwin or other similar 3rd party tools really is outside of the spirit of the question.  This was directed towards a "Windows" way of doing it.  I'm glad you've found a method that works for you.

Comment: I believe that bash for Windows is fully supported by Microsoft now https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about .  It's labeled "beta" but I think there is enough momentum behind it that, at least I, can count on it. I will hazard a guess that the convergence is being driven by Azure, which, to attract *nix-y customers, must make Windows more friendly for them. I agree that Cygwin is not in the Windows spirit, but I think bash for Windows is, at least if my guess is right.

Comment: Until you can install it on a base install of the OS... it's not *standard*.  as-is, you must install a developer version of Windows just to get the option to install it.

Answer (score 1):

Is your AppData folder set to be hidden? If you can see it in Explorer (which you say you can), right click on it and uncheck the Hidden option. Then you should be able to see it with dir.

edit: if it was hidden, the reason you can see it in Explorer is because of your Folder Options for Explorer for "View Hidden Files and Folders"

edit2: I misread your post and assumed you COULD see AppData, but you were just talking about the path. If you go to C:\Users\YoursTruly and you cannot see the AppData folder, then you need to change your Folder Options to view it as a hidden folder. Then you can make AppData a visible folder and it won't matter.

Comment: Thanks.  The optimal answer would have been a merge of yours and TheCompWiz's.  I picked TheCompWiz's because it seems to be somewhat more general, since (as I just discovered), some hidden paths (e.g. `C:\Users\Yours Truly\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft`) cannot be "unhidden", but `dir /ad` will display them.

Comment: All things can be unhidden.  If the folder is marked "read-only" or "system" it will not permit you to remove the "hidden" attribute.  You must first (or at the same time) remove the system/read-only attributes, and then the hidden attribute.  `attrib -r -s -h "C:\Some Folder"`  This is not recommended to do... as it disables a lot of security features in Windows.

Comment: I appreciate your comment, kjo. And I definitely agree with you CompWiz. There's little advantage to unhiding a folder when you have the option to see hidden folders in both Explorer and on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

They are hidden folders. You need to go into the Organize Menu > Folder and Search Options > View Tab > Show hidden files and folders. Then you will be able to see them.

Comment: My thought was that the Show Hidden Files and Folders option was already enabled for OP. That's why he/she can see them in Windows Explorer. But AppData is still technically a hidden folder, which dir must not pick up. I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

None of this worked for me in windows 8 pro. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out what. Heaven help MSFT if it is nearly impossible to get a simple dir or copy command to work without becoming a contortionist, ejecting a full head of hair onto the floor and lining up for triple bypass surgery.