# How to make AppData directory appear in File Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-explorer, cmd.exe, dir

[This post](https://superuser.com/questions/436466/why-doesnt-dir-show-c-users-yours-truly-appdata/436473#436473) outlines how to make the `AppData` directory show up at the DOS prompt, but how do I make it show up in File Explorer (on Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit)? Is there a global setting? Also, what is the file permission under properties that makes it hidden or not? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### How do I make AppData show up in File Explorer?

1. Menu "Tools" > "Folder options..."
2. Click "View" tab
3. Scroll down till you see "Hidden files and folders"
4. Enable "Show hidden files, folders, and drives"
5. Click "OK"

   [image]

---

#### What is the file permission under properties that makes it hidden or not?

1. Right click `AppData` folder
2. Select "Properties"
3. Click "General" tab
4. Enable/Disable "Hidden" as appropriate

   [image]

Comment: Great answer. I wish I could give you more points for it. Hope you get many upvotes.

Comment: @JordanJamingsons Thanks ;) If we are really lucky your question will appear on [hot network questions](http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot). That gives it a lot more exposure (and usually votes) ;)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 the process is similar. Let's say you want to see the folder AppData from user, which is a [common request](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_files-insiderplat_pc/appdata-folder-in-file-explorer-not-visible/a6b34b9c-14bd-4cee-8266-958369e5eb9e).

You'd go to the user folder

[image]

then in the folder top menu click in "View" (instead of being in "Home")

[image]

and you'll see a checkbox saying "Hidden Items". Tick it and the hidden folders will appear.

[image]